# How to get the intersection of a polygon with others in the same geodataframe?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a shapefile that contains thousands of polygons. Lots of them touch but don't cross. I need to get the public line of the touched polygon.

I tried using the following function to achieve my purpose, but the output shows some `MultiLineString` with lines only having two points, which should be a whole `LineString`.

```py
def calcu_intersect_lines(cgidf):

    intersection = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['geometry'], crs=cgidf.crs)

    while len(cgidf) > 1:
        choose = cgidf.iloc[0]
        cgidf.drop(cgidf.index[0], inplace=True)
        for i in range(len(cgidf.index)):
            cgids = cgidf.iloc[i]
            if choose.geometry.exterior.intersects(cgids.geometry.exterior):
                intersects = choose.geometry.exterior.intersection(cgids.geometry.exterior)
                index = len(intersection)
                intersection.loc[index] = [intersects]

            else:
                continue

        return intersection
```

For the `MultiLineString`, I tried using the `shapely.geometry.LineString.union()` function to join two short lines in the same `MultiLineString` if they touch with each other. But the result shows a `MultiLineString` too.

geopandas itself's intersection function seems to result in a `MultiLineString` too.

Is there any method returning a normal result (`LineString` not `MultiLineString` for a continuous public line)?

---

Here is a small example of input and output data:

```py
a = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 0.5), (0.5, 1), (1, 0.5), (1, 0), (0.5, -0.5), (0, 0)))
b = Polygon(((0, 0.5), (0.5, 1), (1, 0.5), (1, 2), (0, 0.5)))
c = Polygon(((1, 0.5), (1, 0), (0.5, -0.5), (1.5, -1), (1, 0.5)))
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['geometry'], data = [a, b, c])
h = calcu_intersect_lines(gdf)
```

Here are the values of `h`:

```
index  geometry
0      MULTILINESTRING ((0 0.5, 0.5 1), (0.5 1, 1 0.5))
1      MULTILINESTRING ((1 0.5, 1 0), (1 0, 0.5 -0.5))
```

The `LineString` in the two `MultiLineString` have public point `(0.5, 1)` and `(1, 0)`, respectively.

The result I want is like the following:

```
index  geometry
0      LINESTRING (0 0.5, 0.5 1, 1 0.5))
1      LINESTRING (1 0.5, 1 0, 0.5 -0.5))
```

---

**Possible solution:**

In the comments, I was proposed to replace the following line

```
intersection.loc[index] = [intersects]
```

by

```
intersection.loc[index] = [LineString([*intersects[0].coords, *map(lambda x: x.coords[1], intersects[1:])])]
```

It works well in my simple example. However, for the true shapefile, it will be much more complicated than that. There might be the following situations:

1. Two polygons with more than one public line.

   ```py
   from shapely.geometry import Polygon

   a = Polygon(((0., 0.), (0., 0.5), (0.5, 1.), (1., 0.5), (1., 0.), (0.5, -0.5), (0., 0.)))
   b = Polygon(((0., 0.5), (0.5, 1.), (1.2, 0.7), (1., 0.), (0.5, -0.5), (2., 0.5), (0., 2.)))
   ```

   For `a` and `b`, they have two pubilc lines `LineString(((0., 0.5), (0.5, 1.)))` and `LineString(((1., 0.), (0.5, -0.5)))`. In this case I can simply use `intersects` function to test if lines touch. But then there is another problem:
2. The lines in a `MultiLineString` are not in order.

   ```py
   from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString

   ml = MultiLineString((((2, 3), (3, 4)), ((0, 2), (2, 3))))
   ```

   For `ml`, this suggestion will return a wrong result.
   Do you have any idea about the 2nd example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Georgy and other contributors' help, I have solved my problem.
The function `shapely.ops.linemerge()` introducted in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/223447/139614) is the key point of my solution.

I post my solution in here:

```py
from shapely import ops

def union_multils(ml):

    '''Union touched LineStrings in MultiLineString or GeometryCollection.

    Parameter
    ---------
    ml: GeometryCollection, MultiLineString or LineString

    return
    ------
    ul: MultiLineString or LineString: a MultiLineString suggest the LineStrings 
        in input ml is not connect entitly.
    '''

    # Drop Point and other geom_type(if exist) out
    ml = list(ml)
    ml = [l for l in ml if l.geom_type == 'LineString']

    # Union
    if len(ml) ==  1 and ml[0].geom_type == 'LineString':
        ul = ml[0]
    else:
        ul = ops.linemerge(ml)

    return ul
```